# Query tables in Apache Drill without adding in extensions to the table name

Tags: apache-drill

I have an Apache Drill setup with the following storage plugin

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "file:///",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
    "csv": {
      "location": "/home/user/data/csv",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": "csv",
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
    "parquet": {
      "location": "/home/user/data/parquet",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": "parquet",
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "skipFirstLine": true,
      "extractHeader": true,
      "delimiter": ","
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet",
      "autoCorrectCorruptDates": false
    }
  },
  "enabled": true
}
```

The name has been configured to `foo`.

The issue is that I wanted to write a query where the name of the table does not have the extension.

I tried the following,

```sql
select * from foo.csv.`agency` limit 100
```

I get the following response

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 21: Object 'agency' not found within 'foo.csv' [Error Id: 80be4497-b71c-47dd-bc2c-6abfa425d55a on nn-hadoop-1:30112]
```

But this works

```sql
select * from foo.csv.`agency.csv` limit 100
```

Is there a way for me to not suffix the table name (file name) with the file extension when I create my query? I have included the `defaultInputFormat` in the workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this issue. Instead of querying files directly, I put the file I wanted to query into a directory and queried the directory instead.

https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-directories/

So, now I have created a folder called `agency` and moved the file `agency.csv` is inside this folder. Now I can do

```sql
select * from foo.csv.`/agency` limit 100
```

and I am getting the results I was looking for.

Comment: You can query the table or file.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the table or file.
For the table please create it:

```
select * from foo.csv.`agency.csv`
```

and query:

```
select * from agency;
```

For the second case, Drill should have a full path to the file or directory (including workspace, if you use it)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a view; first use a writable workspace (like /tmp above)

```
use foo.tmp;
```

Then create the view

```
create view agency as select * from foo.csv.`agency.csv`;
```

Unlike creating a table, a view does not take a significant disk space, and would reflect the latest data in the file (in case the file is updated.)
The usage is the same, like

```
select * from agency limit 100;
```